# Within a list of dicts, processing all key-value pairs per iteration

Tags: python, json, list, loops, dictionary

Having troubles parsing a list of dictionaries, accessing all key-value pairs per dictionary, through a loop in order to process each k-v at a time.

I have a json file that consists of a list of dictionaries.
In simplified form:

```
[
{"": "0", "a": "3893", "b": "2389", "c": "1209"}, 
{"": "1", "a": "4308", "b": "4560", "c": "9127"},
... 
]
```

I want to loop through this per dictionary, and for each key-value pair (excluding the first one, assuming it will be skipped because the key is empty) per iteration, having access to the a,b,c k-v pairs of one dict, so that they are individually processed.

I tried:

```
import json

with open("file.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)

    result_list = []
    for d in data:
        result_list.append([v for k,v in d.items()])

    for k, v in enumerate(result_list.items()): 
        # process each key-value pair
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "somescript.py", line 28, in <module>
    for k, v in enumerate(result_list.items()): 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Meanwhile I tried:

```
import json

with open("file.json", "r") as read_file:
data = json.load(read_file)

for i in data:
    print(i, data[i])
```

And get:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "somescript.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(i, dat[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

The code is faulty, I don't yet know how to achieve the above, it may be simple but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: There are multiple syntax errors in your data and code. Please post code that you've actually tested.

Comment: Anyway, assuming reasonable fixes to your post, `result_list` is a list of lists containing the values in each dictionaries. A list doesn't have an `items` method. Just remove `.items()` if you want to iterate it.

Comment: Your 'c' elements in the dictionary aren't separated by `:`; do you have the code you've been using?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, some errors, I made corrections, but the used data and code are  almost exact copies of the original. The code is 1-on-1.

Comment: So, do you understand what the error messages mean? Because they're pretty clear if you know some python vocabulary. If not, what don't you understand?

Comment: "I want to loop through this per dictionary, and for each key-value pair" This suggests that you need a nested loop.

Comment: Thank you. Also to Blorgbeard. I understand most terminology but not their entire implications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    result_list = []
    for d in data:
        result_list.append([v for k,v in d.items()])
```

This creates a list of lists. Note that when you do this, you are throwing away the keys in your dictionaries. This probably isn't what you want.

```
    for k, v in enumerate(result_list.items()): 
        # process each key-value pair
```

You get an error here because `result_list` is a list, not a dictionary. Lists do not have a method named `items()`.

I suggest instead that you iterate over `data` directly. There is no need for `result_list`:

```
for d in data:
    for k, v in d.items():
        # process each key-value pair
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually worked perfectly and was exactly what I tried to do. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your problem is in your enumerate call:

```
    for k, v in enumerate(result_list): # take off the .items())
        # process each key-value pair
```

You don't invoke .items() on the result_list; enumerate consumes it as a list.

Answering the second of your problems:

```
import json

with open("file.json", "r") as read_file:
data = json.load(read_file)

for i in data:
    print(i, data[i])
```

Assuming that json is a list of dictionaries like you've been using, you'll need to:

```
for item in data:
    for key in item:
        print(key, item[key])
```

to account for double-dereferencing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load the entire list without rebuilding it just using `json.load`, then iterate over it and the dicts

```
import json

with open("file.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)

for d in data:
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items()):
        print(i, k, v)
```

That said I suggest you save the file as a normal JSON file as it seems the first key/value in each dict is supposed to be an `ID` field so it should look as follows:

```
{  
    "0": {
        "a":"3893",
        "b":"2389",
        "c":"1209"
    },
    "1": {
        "a":"4308",
        "b":"4560",
        "c":"9127"
    }
}
```

Which you can do using a dict comprehension:

```
with open("file.json", 'w') as out_file:
    json.dump({d.pop(""): d for d in data}, out_file, indent=4)
```

Then all you'd need to do is simply iterate over the dicts:

```
with open("file.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)

    for _id, item in data.items():
        for k, v in item.items():
            print(_id, k, v)
```

Comment: From what I can tell, the input is a JSON array of objects, not a file with one object per line.

Comment: Yes, I realized that, fixing